# To merge more than one list of table data and save as csv format using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

From the following code, when I iterate and print, then I get all table data, but but when I store as csv format using pandas, then I get only the first list of table data. How to store all of them into a single CSV file?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
isins = ['LU0526609390:EUR','IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR']

for isin in isins:
    html = requests.get(f'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s={isin}').content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    dfs = df_list
    #print(dfs)
    for df in dfs:
        df.to_csv('data.csv', header=False, index=True)
        #print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to collect the data frames in `dfs`, loop over it and generate csv files.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


isins=['LU0526609390:EUR','IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR']


dfs = []
for isin in isins:
    html = requests.get(f'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s={isin}').content
    dfs.extend(pd.read_html(html))

df = pd.concat(dfs) 
df.to_csv('data.csv' , header=False, index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks but they're  producing separate files

Comment: Correct - Are you interested in 1 file only? See latest code.

Comment: How to concatenate them into single file?

Comment: @TestMe code was modified. Give it a try

Comment: Yes, interested in 1 file only?

Comment: As I **wrote** above - the code was modified.

Answer (score 0):

Loop was overwited file. This not saves it as one file bur each file for each iteration, but you get what was wrong

```
isins=['LU0526609390:EUR','IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR']
k = 0
for isin in isins:
    html = requests.get(f'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s={isin}').content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    dfs = df_list
    #print(dfs)
    for df in dfs:
        df.to_csv(str(k)+'data.csv' , header=False, index=True)
        #print(df)
        k = k+1
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy answer would be to use pd.concat() to create a new df and save this. What do you want the csv to look like though, as the result of this concatenation would be.
["CSV"]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvZ1X.png

I don't know whether this is sufficient, as the data is not really labelled (might be problem, if you plan to search for more than two funds).

```
import requests
    import pandas as pd
    funds = ['LU0526609390:EUR', 'IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR']

    for fund in funds:
        html = requests.get(f'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s={fund}').content
        df_list = pd.read_html(html)
        df_final = pd.concat(df_list)
        # print(df_final)
        df_final.to_csv('data.csv', header=False, index=True)
```

(I replaced isin with fund, as isin is already used in python.)